# How to change bytes to hexadecimal using Python?

Tags: python, hex, byte

I'm doing a project in Python that requires me to slice data into bytes and express the results in hexadecimal format. Here's a simplified version of my code which shows only ONE byte:

```
hex_value = 0xff
hex_as_byte = str(hex(hex_value)).encode()
print(hex_as_byte) # The result is b'0xff' which is what I want.
the_byte = hex_as_byte[2:4] # (In my actual code, I also slice 4:6, 6:8, etc.)
print(the_byte) # The result is b'ff'. How do I convert that to b'0xff'?
```

Comment: b'0x' + the_byte

Comment: Thank you. I now realize that this stripped-down code isn't quite right, and furthermore, that my understanding of the whole problem was wrong, but yours is certainly the correct answer to the question I asked. EDIT: And I think I can figure it out based on your answer.